# MySQLi + num_rows depois de uma consulta de tabela

Tags: php, mysqli, login

Isso é para ser um sistema de login com níveis de acessos que eu estou tentando fazer, porem esta dando um erro.

Em que eu estou errando?

Já tentei de tudo e nada. Já olhei a documentação do PHP e nada.

Queria que fosse Mysqli orientado ao objeto, não PDO.

```
<?php

// inclusao do arquivo de conexao ao banco de dados
include("conexao.php");

// se existir o clicar do botao logar do formulario
if(isset($_POST['logar'])){

    // se existir o login do usuario digitado
    if(isset($_POST['loginUsuario'])){

        // verificação de anti injeção de SQL do campo login do usuario
        $loginUsuario = $conexao->escape_string($_POST['loginUsuario']);

        //se existir a senha do usuario digitado
        if(isset($_POST['senhaUsuario'])){

            // verificação de anti injeção de SQL do campo senha do usuario
            $senhaUsuario = $conexao->escape_string($_POST['senhaUsuario']);

            $consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE loginUsuario = $loginUsuario AND senhaUsuario = $senhaUsuario";
            $resultado = $conexao->query($consulta);
            $linha = $conexao->num_rows($resultado);

            echo $linha;// Aqui queria que dizesse que existe o registro pelo login do usuario
                        // Eu digitasse login: admin e senha: 123, aparecesse 1, porque tem dentro do registro
                        // E se digitasse qualquer outra coisa aparecesse 0, porque não tem dentro do registro

        }// isset do campo senha do usuario
    }// isset do campo login do usuario
}//isset botão logar

?>
```

Comment: Aparece algum erro?

Comment: Qual erro aparece?

Comment: Erro 500, eu estou fazendo essa aplicação dentro do meu servidor hospedado.

Comment: https://weec-sistemas.000webhostapp.com/login.php

coloca qualquer coisa no login para vc ver o erro.

Comment: Precisa habilitar a visualização dos erros. Adicione essas duas linhas no começo do script. `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Vou colocar agora, vamos ver.

Comment: obrigado pela dica.

Comment: deu esse erro agora

Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::num_rows() in /storage/ssd3/459/3838459/public_html/login.php on line 24

Comment: ja alterei, porem da o mesmo erro. meu script esta acima o que estou errando?

Comment: Esse é o login.php, porem que esta tudo dentro de uma pagina.

Comment: Abaixo da ultima linha do codigo tem um include para chamar a pagina header.php e um formulario com campos login senha e botão, logo em seguida outro include com footer.php e um mysqli_close();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);

    // inclusao do arquivo de conexao ao banco de dados
    include("conexao.php");

    // se existir o clicar do botao logar do formulario
    if(isset($_POST['logar'])){

        // se existir o login do usuario digitado
        if(isset($_POST['loginUsuario'])){

            // verificação de anti injeção de SQL do campo login do usuario
            $loginUsuario = $conexao->escape_string($_POST['loginUsuario']);

            //se existir a senha do usuario digitado
            if(isset($_POST['senhaUsuario'])){

                // verificação de anti injeção de SQL do campo senha do usuario
                $senhaUsuario = $conexao->escape_string($_POST['senhaUsuario']);

                //************** correção foi aqui ************************* 
                $consulta = $conexao->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE loginUsuario='$loginUsuario' AND senhaUsuario = '$senhaUsuario'");
                $linha = $consulta->num_rows;

                echo $linha;

            }// isset do campo senha do usuario
        }// isset do campo login do usuario
    }//isset botão logar

    // inclusão do arquivo cabeçario da pagina HTML5
    include("header.php");    
?>
 <center>
    <h1>Entre para logar</h1>
 <!-- formulario de login e senha do usuario -->
 <form action="login.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="loginUsuario" maxlength="15" size="15" placeholder="Usuario">
    <input type="password" name="senhaUsuario" maxlength="15" size="15" placeholder="********">
    <input type="submit" name="logar" value="Logar">    
 </form>
</center>

<?php
    // inclusão do arquivo rodape do HTML5
    include("footer.php");
    //fechar banco de dados 
    $conexao->close();
 ?>
```

> OBS: Envolva as variáveis da consulta com aspas simples
>
> `WHERE login='$loginUsuario' AND senha = '$senha'"`

[**num_rows**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) - Obtém o número de linhas em um resultado

### Primeiro caso

```
$consulta = $conexao->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE loginUsuario='$loginUsuario' AND senhaUsuario = '$senhaUsuario'");
//numero de linhas afetadas
$linha = $consulta->num_rows;
```

**ou**

```
$linha = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);
```

### Segundo caso

**conforme resposta do** [[[image: rray]]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/262013/mysqli-num-rows-depois-de-uma-consulta-de-tabela/262027#262027) `rray` e envolvendo as variáveis da consulta com aspas simples.

```
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE loginUsuario='$loginUsuario' AND senhaUsuario = '$senhaUsuario'";
$resultado = $conexao->query($consulta);
$linha = $resultado->num_rows;
```

Comment: @WesleyRodrigues olha lá na sua resposta editada por mim. Coloquei o código do seu link com a correção sugerida ao longo dos comentarios

Comment: eu copiei seu codigo e coloquei la no site porem ainda da erro, será que não é da hospedagem? pq no seu funciona e o no meu não

Comment: Correta `$consulta = $conexao->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE loginUsuario='$loginUsuario' AND senhaUsuario = '$senhaUsuario'");`
`

Comment: esta essa la $consulta = $conexao->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE loginUsuario='$loginUsuario' AND senhaUsuario = '$senhaUsuario'");

Comment: Foi aqui o seu ne? Eu estava fazendo a sintase errada da consulta, por mais que o editor não dava como erro no codigo, o ambiente mostrava um erro de não ter propriedade no codigo num_rows, o usuario @Leo Caracciolo mostrou a forma correta e o meu erro.

Answer (score 1):

Para questao de apreendizado vou estar dispobilizando o codigo inteiro via texto no link

[Codigo](https://weec-sistemas.000webhostapp.com/codigo.txt)

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);

    // inclusao do arquivo de conexao ao banco de dados
    include("conexao.php");

    // se existir o clicar do botao logar do formulario
    if(isset($_POST['logar'])){

        // se existir o login do usuario digitado
        if(isset($_POST['loginUsuario'])){

            // verificação de anti injeção de SQL do campo login do usuario
            $loginUsuario = $conexao->escape_string($_POST['loginUsuario']);

            //se existir a senha do usuario digitado
            if(isset($_POST['senhaUsuario'])){

                // verificação de anti injeção de SQL do campo senha do usuario
                $senhaUsuario = $conexao->escape_string($_POST['senhaUsuario']);

                //************** correção foi aqui ************************* 
                $consulta = $conexao->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE loginUsuario='$loginUsuario' AND senhaUsuario = '$senhaUsuario'");
                $linha = $consulta->num_rows;

                echo $linha;

            }// isset do campo senha do usuario
        }// isset do campo login do usuario
    }//isset botão logar

    // inclusão do arquivo cabeçario da pagina HTML5
    include("header.php");    
?>
 <center>
    <h1>Entre para logar</h1>
 <!-- formulario de login e senha do usuario -->
 <form action="login.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="loginUsuario" maxlength="15" size="15" placeholder="Usuario">
    <input type="password" name="senhaUsuario" maxlength="15" size="15" placeholder="********">
    <input type="submit" name="logar" value="Logar">    
 </form>
</center>

<?php
    // inclusão do arquivo rodape do HTML5
    include("footer.php");
    //fechar banco de dados 
    $conexao->close();
 ?>
```

Comment: corrigi os nomes das colunas aqui tambem :)

Comment: Show de bola, era esse o meu problema, obrigado. questão respondida.

Comment: Agora posso voltar a estudar, Obrigado a todos.

Comment: não esqueça de marcar uma resposta como aceita, veja como e porque em  https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Comment: abre uma resposta sua, essa eu não consigo marcar pq é minha propria resposta mesmo vc editando não consigo marcar

Comment: A resposta não estava completa mas estava correta, só que atacando os pontos criticos, de qq forma comecei colocando o codigo completo

Comment: Então coloca uma resposta com o codigo que vc alterou, para eu marcar no seu nome e colocar algumas observações do problema para outra pessoa quando vim ver ser orientado

Answer (score 0):

Quem tem a informação do retorno de linhas da consulta é resource e não a conexão.

Mude:

```
$linha = $conexao->num_rows($resultado);
```

Para:

```
$linha = $resultado->num_rows;
```

Comment: Eu alterei e olha la um outro erro, estou vindo ate vcs por estou a 3 dias pesquisando na internet e testando de todas as maneiras.